# Need help identifying subject in sentence with a conjunction

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality, conjunctions

Currently, I am involved in a disagreement as to interpreting the grammatical meaning of the following sentence:

“Restores 10% of Att as HP in battle.”

Given that “Att” and “HP” are nouns (with numerical values, if that makes a difference), from a purely grammatical standpoint does this sentence mean that either:

1. 10% of “Att” is restored
2. 10% of “HP” is restored
3. Neither, something different, or is not grammatically correct

Edit for clarity:

> The sentence represents the effect of an item in an MMORPG. "Att" is a
>   numerical value for "Attack Power" and "HP" is a different numerical
>   value for "Health Points." We are in agreement that the intended
>   meaning of the sentence is that "HP" is restored by an amount equal to
>   10% of "Att." The dispute is regarding whether the given sentence is a
>   grammatically correct way of conveying the given meaning. Under
>   assumptions #1 or #3 it would not be correct while under assumption #2
>   it would be correct. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: It's not possible to ignore the context if you want a sensible answer to your question.

Comment: I'm not sure of the best way to give context. The sentence represents the effect of an item in an MMORPG. "Att" is a numerical value for "Attack Power" and "HP" is a different numerical value for "Health Points." We are in agreement that the intended meaning of the sentence is that "HP" is restored by an amount equal to 10% of "Att." The dispute is regarding whether the given sentence is a grammatically correct way of conveying the given meaning. Under assumptions #1 or #3 it would not be correct while under assumption #2 it would be correct. Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the HP increases by 10% of the current ATT value whilst the ATT value remains the same: then the statement is incorrect.

I understand it to mean, 10% of the current ATT value will be deducted and given as HP.

If the former is what actually happens in game, then it should say;

Restores HP by 10% of ATT value.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that in the light of your explanation, your statement that

> We are in agreement that the intended meaning of the sentence is that "HP" is restored by an amount equal to 10% of "Att."

represents a justifiable interpretation. In the context of the explanation, I also find no problem with the wording of your query sentence, despite its terseness.

It is also evident that neither of your propositions 1) or 2) means the same as what you and your fellow gamers have agreed the query sentence means; but that meaning is covered (vaguely) by the 'something different' component of 3).

Answer (score 1):

"restored" is not the right word.  . There is no reason to believe HP is "restored"; that would entail returning it to its prior value, which I presume is unknown (that is, it could vary by situation). What if HP's prior value were lower? You would have to REDUCE it in order to "restore" it. What if increasing HP by 10% of Att brought HP to a higher vale than it had ever been? That would not be "restoring" either!  And "replenish" would involve similar conundrums.

So it should say that HP is "increased" or "augmented" by 10% of the value of Att.